# How I can calculate the fractional part of this number

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let us consider this real number:

$$z=\frac{(-\sqrt3+2)^{2^{p-2}}+(\sqrt3+2)^{2^{p-2}}}{2^{p}-1}$$

My **question** is: How I can calculate the **fractional part** of this number for big natural number $p$. I remark that $0<(-\sqrt3+2)^{2^{p-2}}<1$ for all $p$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_{1}=2-\sqrt{3},x_{1}=2+\sqrt{3}\\x^2-sx+p=0\\x^2-(2-\sqrt{3}+2+\sqrt{3})x+(2-\sqrt{3})(2+\sqrt{3})=0\\x^2-4x+1=0\\a_{n+2}-4a_{n+1}+a_{n}=0$$may be help you

Comment: @ darya khosrotash: How this can help for this situation.

Comment: I am thinking ...

Comment: Can binomial theorem solve $2^p-1$?

Comment: @user45195: I do not know.

Comment: Also, if ${(-\sqrt3+2)^2}^{p-2}$ in the numerator is between 0 and 1, can't it be considered negligible, with extremely large p and therefore, even larger denominator?

Comment: @user45195: Yes, and what happen next.

Comment: By the way, I meant the rules for factorizing $a^n+b^n$ and $a^n-b^n$. I accidentally wrote binomial theorem.

Comment: as in identity 7 and 11 of this site: http://www.mathwords.com/f/factoring_rules.htm

Comment: Using identity 7, we get $2^p-1=2^{p-1}+2^{p-2}+2^{p-3}+\cdots+2^2+2$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash: How I can relate my question to your answer?